# How to avoid the browser cache with php/php5?

Tags: php

I have a php application that need not store the cache of the browser, as I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write this on the top of your php code

```
<?php
header( "Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT" );  // disable IE caching
header( "Last-Modified: " . gmdate( "D, d M Y H:i:s" ) . " GMT" );
header( "Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate" );
header( "Pragma: no-cache" );
?>
```